# Freeze Dom Manipulation

Tags: dom, debugging, firebug

Is there a way to make firebug (or any other browser, or using any other tool) stop any dom manipulation from happening? Sometimes layout debugging a screen filled with on hover events is impossible, as the elements may disappear, and you can't see their compound layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is quite easy to do for pages that are not constantly and autonomously being altered (even comet applications can be relatively stable for a few seconds): just save the page using firefox. It will save the current state of it all, ignoring all javascript and events. More than that, the styles will be easily viewable.

Comment: PS: Currently Chrome has a break on subtree modification option. Much easier to debug than it was 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I freeze DOM Manipulation in FF with Firebug clicking right button on Node and set "Stop when add/change child"

Answer (score 0):

i wish there was a better way to do this, i wonder if it would be possible to do with a bookmarklet, im surprised theres no button in firebug or chrome to just freeze the dom, or is there one, that i dont know about?